# Get Google business reviews server side

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-business

I'm trying to get a list of reviews of my Google business through the API to display them on my website. But I can't figure out how to authenticate the API server side. The documentation only mentions OAuth2.0 authentication from the client side with redirect URLs, but there won't be a client going to a confirmation page in this case.

I just want to be able to perform this request in Node.js:

`GET https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{locationId}/reviews`

I've already submitted the application and been approved for a Business API and enabled the various APIs in my account. I have created OAuth2.0 credentials. I'm just not sure how to move forward from here.

How can I authenticate Google Business API requests on the server?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up putting together an answer through lots of searching. Google documentation is all over the place.

A basic example of getting reviews is below. But to get it to work there are a few steps first.

1. You'll need to add a Service Account in your [API credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)

   - The name, ID, and description aren't particularly important. Just something that makes sense to you
2. Go to the service account details -> keys -> add key -> create new key -> JSON

   - This will download a key file to your computer. **Keep it private.**
3. Grant [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) for your service account

   - To do this, you'll need to be an admin of the account if you're part of an organisation
   - It will ask for a Client ID, but it is called Unique ID in the service account details. They're the same thing.
   - Add whatever scopes you need for the services you want to access. For reviews, the scope listed in the example below is enough.
4. The `subject` field in `google.auth.JWT` needs to be an admin of the account. I used my own email.

That should be it! You should now be able to fill out the values in the example below and access the API from a server. Other services may require different scopes.

You can get [account](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/account-data) and [location](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/location-data) info from the API docs. The endpoints and data formats are fairly well documented. Just authentication isn't very well explained it seems.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import {google} from 'googleapis';

import key from './key.json' assert {type: 'json'};

main();

async function main(){
    const reviews=await getReviews();
}

async function getReviews(){
    const token=await authenticate();
    const accountId='YOUR ACCOUNT ID';
    const locationId='YOUR LOCATION ID';
    const url=`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/`+
          `${accountId}/locations/${locationId}/reviews`;
    const resp=await axios.get(url, {
        headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    });
    return resp.data.reviews;
}

async function authenticate(){
    const scopes=[
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage'
    ];

    const jwt=new google.auth.JWT({
        email: key.client_email,
        key: key.private_key,
        subject: 'ADMIN EMAIL',
        scopes
    });

    const resp=await jwt.authorize();
    return resp.access_token.replace(/\.{2,}/g, '');
}
```